# How to extract specific column value from a CSV file converted into a Plist file?

Tags: swift, csv, filter, plist, nspredicate

I converted a `CSV` file into a `Plist` file, and imported it into my Xcode project,

the content of the Plist file can be found below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>"Section designation","Mass per metre (kg/m)","Depth of section, h (mm)","Width of section, b (mm)","Web thickness, tw (mm)","Flange thickness, tf (mm)","Root radius, r (mm)","Depth between fillets, d (mm)"</key>
            <string>1016 x 305x 584,584.0,1056.0,314.0,36.0,64.0,30.0,868.1</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>"Section designation","Mass per metre (kg/m)","Depth of section, h (mm)","Width of section, b (mm)","Web thickness, tw (mm)","Flange thickness, tf (mm)","Root radius, r (mm)","Depth between fillets, d (mm)"</key>
            <string>1016 x 305x 494,494.0,1036.0,309.0,31.0,54.0,30.0,868.1</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>"Section designation","Mass per metre (kg/m)","Depth of section, h (mm)","Width of section, b (mm)","Web thickness, tw (mm)","Flange thickness, tf (mm)","Root radius, r (mm)","Depth between fillets, d (mm)"</key>
            <string>1016 x 305x 438,438.0,1026.0,305.0,26.9,49.0,30.0,868.1</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>"Section designation","Mass per metre (kg/m)","Depth of section, h (mm)","Width of section, b (mm)","Web thickness, tw (mm)","Flange thickness, tf (mm)","Root radius, r (mm)","Depth between fillets, d (mm)"</key>
            <string>1016 x 305x 415,415.0,1020.0,304.0,26.0,46.0,30.0,868.1</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>"Section designation","Mass per metre (kg/m)","Depth of section, h (mm)","Width of section, b (mm)","Web thickness, tw (mm)","Flange thickness, tf (mm)","Root radius, r (mm)","Depth between fillets, d (mm)"</key>
            <string>1016 x 305x 393,392.7,1015.9,303.0,24.4,43.9,30.0,868.1</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>"Section designation","Mass per metre (kg/m)","Depth of section, h (mm)","Width of section, b (mm)","Web thickness, tw (mm)","Flange thickness, tf (mm)","Root radius, r (mm)","Depth between fillets, d (mm)"</key>
            <string>1016 x 305x 350,350.0,1008.0,302.0,21.1,40.0,30.0,868.1</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>"Section designation","Mass per metre (kg/m)","Depth of section, h (mm)","Width of section, b (mm)","Web thickness, tw (mm)","Flange thickness, tf (mm)","Root radius, r (mm)","Depth between fillets, d (mm)"</key>
            <string>1016 x 305x 314,314.3,999.9,300.0,19.1,35.9,30.0,868.1</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>"Section designation","Mass per metre (kg/m)","Depth of section, h (mm)","Width of section, b (mm)","Web thickness, tw (mm)","Flange thickness, tf (mm)","Root radius, r (mm)","Depth between fillets, d (mm)"</key>
            <string>1016 x 305x 272,272.3,990.1,300.0,16.5,31.0,30.0,868.1</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>"Section designation","Mass per metre (kg/m)","Depth of section, h (mm)","Width of section, b (mm)","Web thickness, tw (mm)","Flange thickness, tf (mm)","Root radius, r (mm)","Depth between fillets, d (mm)"</key>
            <string>1016 x 305x 249,248.7,980.1,300.0,16.5,26.0,30.0,868.1</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>"Section designation","Mass per metre (kg/m)","Depth of section, h (mm)","Width of section, b (mm)","Web thickness, tw (mm)","Flange thickness, tf (mm)","Root radius, r (mm)","Depth between fillets, d (mm)"</key>
            <string>1016 x 305x 222,222.0,970.3,300.0,16.0,21.1,30.0,868.1</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</plist>
```

After importing the Plist file into my Xcode project, I would like to extract all the corresponding values for a specific column value as illustrated in the code below:

```
import UIKit

class UniversalBeamsViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        print(getDataForSectionDesignation(sectionDesignation: "1016 x 305x 584"))

    }

    func getSwiftArrayFromPlist(name: String) -> (Array<Dictionary<String, String>>) {

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "plist")

        let array = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!)

        return ((array as? Array<Dictionary<String, String>>)!)

    }

    func getDataForSectionDesignation(sectionDesignation: String) -> (Array<[String: String]>) {

        let array = getSwiftArrayFromPlist(name: "UB 1016x305 series")

        let namePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "Section designation == %@", sectionDesignation)

        return [array.filter {namePredicate.evaluate(with: $0)}[0]]

    }

}
```

However, every time I run the App I keep on getting the below error message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format
>   string "Section designation = %@"'

Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,
Shadi.

Comment: That's not how you want your data in the plist. It should be an array of arrays.

Comment: Could you please explain further? My thinking is that you have an array which contains several dictionaries, within each dictionary there is a Key and a correspond Value. Then I just need to locate the specific Key I am looking for in a Dictionary and get all corresponding Value for that specific Dictionary inside the ARRAY?

Comment: First, why would you repeat the column titles over and over and over? The plist should be an array of arrays. The outer array will have an inner array for each row. Each inner array will have a value for each column in that row. The column headings should only be there once as the first entry in the outer array.

Comment: What you are saying makes total sense, as I just realised that I repeated the columns titles multiple times over and over. Could you please provide me with one example of how the code inside the Plist file should look like? As I am not an experienced developer yet.